# Invalid index 0, size 0 android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having a problem with my app. It says invalide index 0, size 0 android sqlite. This is the logcat

```
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.mapeh.subject/com.mapeh.subject.assessment.MusicLessonAssessment}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
  09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
  09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
  09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):  at com.mapeh.subject.musiclesson.GamePlay.getNextQuestion(GamePlay.java:102)
  09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):  at com.mapeh.subject.assessment.MusicLessonAssessment.onCreate(MusicLessonAssessment.java:34)
  09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
  09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
  09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
  09-01 12:58:47.903: E/AndroidRuntime(15196):  ... 11 more
```

This is the code:

```
  private Question currentQ;
private GamePlay currentGame;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.musiclessonassessment);
    /**
     * Configure current game and get question
     */
    currentGame = ((MapehSubjectApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
    currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();  <~~~~~ Error here
    Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    /**
     * Update the question and answer options..
     */
    setQuestions();

}


/**
 * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
 * current question
 */
private void setQuestions() {
    //set the question text from current question
    String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion()) + "?";
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    qText.setText(question);

    //set the available options
    List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
    TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

    TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

    TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

    TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));
}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");

    /**
     * validate a checkbox has been selected
     */
    if (!checkAnswer()) return;


    /**
     * check if end of game
     */
    if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
        //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
        Intent i = new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else{
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MusicLessonAssessment.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


/**
 * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
 * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
 */
private boolean checkAnswer() {
    String answer = getSelectedAnswer();
    if (answer==null){
        //Log.d("Questions", "No Checkbox selection made - returning");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {
            //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementRightAnswers();
        }
        else{
            //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementWrongAnswers();
        }
        return true;
    }
}


/**
 * 
 */
private String getSelectedAnswer() {
    RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    RadioButton c3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    RadioButton c4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    if (c1.isChecked())
    {
        return c1.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c2.isChecked())
    {
        return c2.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c3.isChecked())
    {
        return c3.getText().toString();
    }
    if (c4.isChecked())
    {
        return c4.getText().toString();
    }

    return null;
}
```

**GamePlay.class**

```
   public class GamePlay {

private int numRounds;
private int difficulty;
private String playerName;
private int right;
private int wrong;
private int round;

private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

/**
 * @return the playerName
 */
public String getPlayerName() {
    return playerName;
}
/**
 * @param playerName the playerName to set
 */
public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
    this.playerName = playerName;
}
/**
 * @return the right
 */
public int getRight() {
    return right;
}
/**
 * @param right the right to set
 */
public void setRight(int right) {
    this.right = right;
}
/**
 * @return the wrong
 */
public int getWrong() {
    return wrong;
}
/**
 * @param wrong the wrong to set
 */
public void setWrong(int wrong) {
    this.wrong = wrong;
}
/**
 * @return the round
 */
public int getRound() {
    return round;
}
/**
 * @param round the round to set
 */
public void setRound(int round) {
    this.round = round;
}
/**
 * @param difficulty the difficulty to set
 */
public void setDifficulty(int difficulty) {
    this.difficulty = difficulty;
}
/**
 * @return the difficulty
 */
public int getDifficulty() {
    return difficulty;
}
/**
 * @param questions the questions to set
 */
public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
}

/**
 * @param q the question to add
 */
public void addQuestions(Question q) {
    this.questions.add(q);
}

/**
 * @return the questions
 */
public List<Question> getQuestions() {
    return questions;
}


public Question getNextQuestion(){

    //get the question
    Question next = questions.get(this.getRound());   <~~~~~ Error here
    //update the round number to the next round
    this.setRound(this.getRound()+1);
    return next;
}

/**
 * method to increment the number of correct answers this game
 */
public void incrementRightAnswers(){
    right ++;
}

/**
 * method to increment the number of incorrect answers this game
 */
public void incrementWrongAnswers(){
    wrong ++;
}
/**
 * @param numRounds the numRounds to set
 */
public void setNumRounds(int numRounds) {
    this.numRounds = numRounds;
}
/**
 * @return the numRounds
 */
public int getNumRounds() {
    return numRounds;
}

/**
 * method that checks if the game is over
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean isGameOver(){
    return (getRound() >= getNumRounds());
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**Code fragment from DBAdapter:**

```
    public List<Question> getQuestionSet(int difficulty, int numQ){
        List<Question> questionSet = new ArrayList<Question>();
        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tblQuestions WHERE Lesson = " + difficulty +
                " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + numQ, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            //Log.d("QUESTION", "Question Found in DB: " + c.getString(1));
            Question q = new Question();
            q.setQuestion(c.getString(1));
            q.setAnswer(c.getString(5));
            q.setOption1(c.getString(2));
            q.setOption2(c.getString(3));
            q.setOption3(c.getString(4));
            q.setRating(difficulty);
            questionSet.add(q);
        }
        return questionSet;
    }
```

CODE:

```
 /**
 * Listener for game menu
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;

    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.assess :
        //once logged in, load the main page
        //Log.d("LOGIN", "User has started the game");

        //Get Question set //
        List<Question> questions = getQuestionSetFromDb();

        //Initialise Game with retrieved question set ///
        GamePlay c = new GamePlay();
        c.setQuestions(questions);
        c.setNumRounds(getNumQuestions());
        ((MapehSubjectApplication)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c);  

        //Start Game Now.. //
        i = new Intent(this, MusicLessonAssessment.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.PLAYBUTTON);
        break;

    case R.id.exit :
        finish();
        break;
    }

}


/**
 * Method that retrieves a random set of questions from
 * the database for the given difficulty
 * @return
 * @throws Error
 */
private List<Question> getQuestionSetFromDb() throws Error {
    int diff = getDifficultySettings();
    int numQuestions = getNumQuestions();
    DBAdapter myDBAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
    try {
        myDBAdapter.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        myDBAdapter.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }
    List<Question> questions = myDBAdapter.getQuestionSet(diff, numQuestions);
    myDBAdapter.close();
    return questions;
}


/**
 * Method to return the difficulty settings
 * @return
 */
private int getDifficultySettings() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
    int diff = settings.getInt(Constants.DIFFICULTY, Constants.MUSIC);
    return diff;
}

/**
 * Method to return the number of questions for the game
 * @return
 */
private int getNumQuestions() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
    int numRounds = settings.getInt(Constants.NUM_ROUNDS, 10);
    return numRounds;
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing here but I believe my database has records, I double checked it. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this two clues:

```
at com.mapeh.subject.musiclesson.GamePlay.getNextQuestion(GamePlay.java:102)

Question next = questions.get(this.getRound());   <~~~~~ Error here
```

obviously `this.getRound()` returns `0`, but `questions` is empty, so there's no `Question` at position 0 uf `questions`. Thus the exception.

Comment: So how can I debug the questions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not added any questions on your *questions* list object(member variable in GamePlay class), resulting having an empty list (size 0), and trying to index it, resulting in an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception, as you don't use anywhere in your code the addQuestions(...) method.

Comment: So what will I do? what will I do with the addQuestions method?

Comment: I suggest that you fill the list with the desired questions in the desired point of code (probably on GamePlay  initialization part).
My point is that you must have questions in your list in order to index them.

Comment: Hi, those questions are already from my pre-populated db. Please check my update post.

Comment: Surely your database may be populated, but when are you actually filling your `GamePlay` object using the data from that database? That is, when and where do you call `setQuestions` (or `addQuestion)` using the results from `getQuestionSet`? Add some more code to your question.

Comment: You still don't add any question to the member list of GamePlay instance.
I suggest that you call after the GamePlay instance getting:
currentGame.setQuestions((ArrayList)DBAdapter.getQuestionSet());|
to have a list with questions in the currentGame,
and you don't need to initialize the list variable in the class, as it is done inside the method getQuestionSet() and you are setting this way the list returned as GamePlay's instance list.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I've added the QUestionActivity code to my post.

Comment: Okay, so you're initializing the application-global game object inside `onClick` and then start your other activity. A bit unusual, but okay I guess. How about some debugging? Step through the code while keeping a watch on the questions inside that game object, see how it changes with every line of code inside `QuestionActivity.onClick` and `MusicLessonAssessment.onCreate`, try to look for unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen that before.. somewhat similar to this one: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/getting-started-complete-android-app_11.html

try this: 
1. double check if you have already updated the data base.
2.use sqlite browser to see if the values on the table of your data base is correct.

after doing that, check for the values on "difficulty" if all values is "1" the when you run the app on the emulator go to setting and select "EASY".. if value is "2" then select "MEDIUM" and so on..

HOPE THIS HELPS..